# Displaying IO arrays

Tags: arrays, haskell, io

As I've been learning haskell I've enjoyed the pure parts but now I am stumbling through the monadic and IO parts and probably experiencing what some people find truly infuriating about the language.  I solving a project euler problem and I simple want a mutable array because I have to update elements frequently by index.  I tried Vectors but couldn't get them working so I tried Data.Array.IO.  I can read and write elements fine but I can't display the array in terminal the way I want. So far I have this.

```
test = do
    arr <- newArray (1,10) 37 :: IO (IOArray Int Int)
    a <- readArray arr 1
    writeArray arr 1 64
    b <- readArray arr 1
    dispArray arr 
    return ()

dispArray arr = do
    (a,b) <- getBounds arr
    printf "["
    dispArray' arr a
    printf "]\n"
        where dispArray' arr i = do
                (a,b) <- getBounds arr
                if i < a || i > b
                    then return ()
                    else do
                        v <- readArray arr i
                        print v
                        dispArray' arr (i+1)
```

The ouput of this as you would expect is this:

```
[64
37
37
37
37
37
37
37
37
37
]
```

But this is inconvenient and I want this `[64,37,37,37....` like this.  I've seen functions that are something like `toList`, but I don't want this.  I don't want to convert to a list everytime I display.  So I figured I would need to use `printf`.  So I replaced `print v` with `printf " %s," (show v)`.  But this doesn't compile. I don't know why.  I thought it would because `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()` and `show :: Show a => a -> String` so why wouldn't it work because `%s` signifies a string?  So I then put to calls next to each other.  To see if printf would even work.

```
printf " %s," "hello"
print v
```

Which compiles and displays:

```
[ hello,64
 hello,37
 hello,37
 hello,37
 hello,37
 hello,37
 hello,37
 hello,37
 hello,37
 hello,37
]
```

Why can I not use `show v`?  Why is haskell IO so infuriating to beginners?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what exactly is the error message you get when trying to compile with `printf " %s," (show v)`?

Comment: ` Could not deduce (PrintfType (m a0))
      arising from the ambiguity check for `dispArray'`
I've tried adding types via `::` but the types for monads I feel are incredibly cryptic.

Comment: Ps this is a good use case for `ST` arrays. They let you have mutable stuff hidden beneath a purely functional interface

Comment: @DiegoNolan: you're on the right track with getting `printf` to work.  The proper type annotation is `printf "%s," v :: IO ()`.  In ghci, you can use `:info PrintfType` to see what instances are in scope, although in the particular case of `PrintfType` that's still pretty cryptic.

Comment: @JohnL Thanks. Yeah I looked at Hoogle. Saw ` PrintfType` and then wondered what that could possibly be.

Comment: @jozefg I looked at ST arrays but thought they looked more complicated.  I looked at Vectors because I read a post that suggested them for most people need.  Do you know if there are some general guidelines for what types to use given some problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JohnL When I use `printf "%s," v :: IO ()` I get `[ *** Exception: Printf.printf: bad argument` at runtime

Comment: @DiegoNolan: that means `v` is a type that printf knows about, but not a `String`.  Similar to if you wrote `printf("%s",1)` in C.  If you use `printf "%s," (show v) :: IO ()` it should work.  `PrintfType` is type class hackery to provide polyvariadic functions, which aren't part of standard Haskell syntax.  That's why it's necessary to provide a type annotation to the compiler; there isn't enough context for the type inferencer to resolve it without some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting type-checking puzzle.

The error message that the call to `printf` produces is

```
Could not deduce (PrintfType (m a0))
  arising from the ambiguity check for `dispArray'
```

The phrases `Could not deduce` and `ambiguity` typically hint at the fact that GHC has
insufficient type information in order to conclude how this program should be typed. This might be a real type error, but it's also possible that it can be fixed simply by providing more type information (and this is the case here).

The culprit here is really `printf`, combined with the flexibility of the mutable array interface, and not so much Haskell's IO system. The type of `printf` is an ingenious hack, but still a hack. In order to know a flexible number of parameters of various types that depend on just the format string, `printf` has a type that isn't very safe nor very informative:

```
printf :: PrintfType r => String -> r
```

So all we really know for sure is that the first argument is of type `String`. The rest can be any type `r` that is in the type class `PrintfType`.

The details of the instances do not matter. What's interesting is that `show` produces a `String`, and if we apply `printf` to a format string and then a `show`-produced second string, we are still left with a rather uninformative type:

```
> :t printf "%s," (show 2)
printf "%s," (show 2) :: PrintfType t => t
```

In particular, there's no indication here that the result is to be in the `IO` monad.

This normally wouldn't be a problem, if GHC could conclude from the context that you're in `IO`. But within `dispArray'`, the only other functions you are calling are `readArray`, `getBounds`, `return` (and `dispArray'` recursively). None of these functions specifies that it lives in `IO` either. In particular, all of the array functions are overloaded over the monad, for example:

```
getBounds :: (Ix i, MArray a e m) => a i e -> m (i, i)
```

(And indeed, `getBounds` could, for example, also work in an `ST` monad context.) So there's simply nothing in `dispArray'` that determines that you live in `IO`. And that in turn means that GHC cannot resolve the type of `printf`.

As I said, it's a consequence of the desired flexibility of `printf` that `printf` itself cannot provide this information, and it has to be available externally.

The solution is easy enough. As suggested in one of the comments, it is sufficient to annotate the result type of the call to `printf`:

```
printf "%s," (show v) :: IO ()
```

As you're using `printf` anyway (and if you're actually only interested in arrays of decimal numbers), you could also use:

```
printf "%d," v :: IO ()
```

It would also sufficient (but less clear to the reader) to give a type signature for anything else within the definition of `dispArray'` so that it fixes the return type to be `IO ()`. For example, you could annotate the `return ()` in the `then`-branch of the `if` expression:

```
return () :: IO ()
```

Answer (score 6):

The incantation you want is:

```
putStr (show v)
```

That prints out `v` without a newline.

Comment: `putStr $ show v` but why can't printf be used if I want to have nice format in less lines?

Comment: It's hard to say unless you make your example easier for me to compile, but my guess is that you are being bitten by the monomorphism restriction because you didn't provide explicit type signatures.  Your error has nothing to do with Haskell `IO`.  GHC just can't infer what the type of `printf` should be because it abuses type class magic a lot.